# Does the Jest --changedSince option also test related files?

Tags: jestjs

I've tried to look at the source code but I am a little confused. Does the Jest changedSince option also test related files?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to be more specific it's doing an inverse resolve of dependents.

When it comes to actually reporting coverage, it will run tests as mentioned, but it will only report the coverage of the changed file(s).